# SwiftUI - string constant to URL link in List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm trying to create a list with the rows linkable to a YouTube video URL (stored as a string). I'm just learning SwiftUI and Swift language, so even an external link to Safari would suffice.

I've tried both navigation links and navigation views with no luck.

I tried the below version, but it gives an error for the record.videour as an argument.
I'm assuming it's because record.videourl is not a "view".

Is there a way to do this without using @state or @observableObjects?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List(records, id: \.id) { record in
            NavigationLink(destination: record.videourl){
                VStack {
                    HStack{
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: record.imagefile))
                            .cornerRadius(4)
                        Text(record.title)
                            .padding(3)
                            .font(.custom("AmericanTypewriter", fixedSize: 15))
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("CradleToGrave R")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I know the string is valid when I print the output. For context, here is how it's loaded and the structure.

```
import Foundation

struct Record: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let imagefile: String
    let videourl: String
}

let records = loadCSV(fileName: "Manual_Playlist")

func parseCSV(contents: String) -> [Record] {
    let rows = contents.components(separatedBy: "\n")
    var records: [Record] = []
    for row in rows {
        let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
        if columns.count == 4 {
            let record = Record(title: columns[0],
                                description: columns[1],
                                imagefile: columns[2],
                                videourl: columns[3])
            
            records.append(record)
        }
    }
    return records
}

func loadCSV(fileName: String) -> [Record] {
    if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "csv") {
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return parseCSV(contents: contents)
        } catch {
            print("Error reading file: \(error)")
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

I've even tried using `videourl` as a URL object with no luck.

Comment: you don't need `NavigationLink`, but just `Link`, e.g. like this: `Link("Wikipedia", destination: URL(string: "https://www.wikipedia.org")!)`

Comment: My destination is in a struct called record with videourl as the string. I want to replace what's in quotes with `record.videourl` but it does not work.

Comment: if you're sure your strings are valid urls just force unwrap with ! like @Nirav D demonstrated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can use the [`Link`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) or [`openURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/openurl) environment key. `NavigationLink` is used to push a new view.

**Using Link**

```
Link("Visit Google", destination: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
   .font(.title)
   .foregroundColor(.green)

//Or with custom view

Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!) {
    Image(systemName: "link.circle.fill")
       .font(.title)
}
```

**Using openURL**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.openURL) var openURL

    var body: some View {
        Button("Visit Google") {
            openURL(URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you have the actual string, "https://www.google.com" I want to replace it with my record.videourl - which should return a string object. 

I get the error, "Value of optional type 'URL?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'URL'"

Comment: @DevGin It's simply `URL(string: record.videourl)!` but make sure you have valid URL other wise your app will crash because of force wrap. If you have doubt on URL you can use `openURL` like this `if let url = URL(string: record.videourl) { openURL(url) }`

Comment: This crashes at runtime every time I try it with `URL(string: record.videourl)!` If I simply printed the videourl with a text view, it prints the correct URL. At least at first glance. Perhaps there are invalid characters in the string that I am unaware of.

Comment: OpenURL does display the links now correctly. There must be something wrong with my CSV import causing incorrect links where I don't want them. This is the solution that worked for me, though.